# I want to reconnect every 30s to server app with Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want client to connect constantly every 30 seconds to server and to make new connection. I want to change the time after which user is disconnected.

Client-side:

```
<script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {
            'reconnect': true,
            'force new connection': true
        });
        socket.on('connect', function (data) {
            socket.emit('storeClientInfo', { customId:"123456789",'sessionId':"asd2131ad113ad" });
        });
</script>
```

Server-side:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var exec = require("child_process");
var people = [];

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    var peop = {};

    socket.on('storeClientInfo', function (data) {
        var status = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('login:' +status);
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            var status = new Date().getTime();
            console.log('logout:' +status);
        });
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Outputs login:

```
login:1416837382116
logout:1416837407535
login:1416837410118
logout:1416837435537
login:1416837438115
```

It is necessary that logout is done exactly after 30 seconds.
I tried changing those values:

```
  io.set('heartbeat timeout', );
  io.set('heartbeat interval', );
```

But i did not succeed in getting right results.

**CODE AFTER EDIT:**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('storeClientInfo', function (data) {
    var userId = data.customId;
    var userIpAddress= socket.request.socket.remoteAddress;
    var status = new Date().getTime()+65000;
    if (typeof people[userId] == 'undefined') {
        people[userId] = {userId: userId,status:status};
        console.log(userId + ' logged. Ip address: '+ userIpAddress);
    } else {
        people[userId] = {userId: userId,status:status};
    }

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
         setTimeout(function () {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            if (typeof people[userId] != 'undefined'){
                if (people[userId].status < now) {
                    exec.exec("php some.php " + data.customId, function(err, stdout, stderr) { console.log(userId + " logout!"); });
                    delete people[userId];
                }
            }
        }, 125000);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Why would you have a configuration where a websocket only stays connected for 30 seconds?  They are designed to stay connected for long periods of time exactly so you don't have to be constantly reconnecting.  If you can explain what problem you're really trying to solve, then perhaps we can direct you to the proper technology or solution.

Comment: The problem is that, i need socket to work after refreshing page or after navigating to other address, e.g. index.php?controller=site. So I try to do it like this: after refreshing page i DO NOT DO planned logout actions, but instead i wait for the next login.
Check code after Edit.